# How do I fix flow error "TouchHistoryMath. Duplicate module provider"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm configuring a new project and have started importing some libraries when I get the following flow error.  What does this error mean and how do I diagnose and fix?  This is a react native project and I recently added the `subscriptions-transport-ws` library.

```
Launching Flow server
Spawned flow server (pid=13272)
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/stack/event/eventPlugins/TouchHistoryMath.js:0
TouchHistoryMath. Duplicate module provider
current provider. See: node_modules/react-native-gesture-responder/library/TouchHistoryMath.js:0
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "node_modules/.bin/flow",
    "flow-stop": "node_modules/.bin/flow stop"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@shoutem/ui": "^0.10.9",
    "apollo-client": "0.8.0",
    "graphql": "^0.9.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^1.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "~15.4.0",
    "react-apollo": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-lock": "^0.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^1.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^4.4.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.5.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.9.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.37.0",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.0"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a bug caused by two modules having the same name. A workaround that solved the issue for me was to tell Flow to ignore one of the modules. In other words, add one (or both) of the following lines under the `[ignore]` section of your .flowconfig file:

```
.*/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/shared/event/eventPlugins/TouchHistoryMath.js
.*/node_modules/react-native-gesture-responder/library/TouchHistoryMath.js
```

Note: the first of these files seems to be part of the core react-native library, while the second comes from a dependency used by @shoutem/ui. I'm not sure if there's any side effects with excluding any of these files from Flow.

Answer (score 1):

You should comment these lines.

```
# UNSUPPORTED - HASTE
#module.system=haste
#module.system.haste.use_name_reducers=true
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebookarchive/node-haste

> Unsupported/Archived Facebook no longer uses node-haste, and this
>   project was not being maintained.